# I need help deciphering an audio file .mp3 file to get an answer. From a game

Tags: frequency-spectrum, noise, frequency

I was given a .mp3 audio file needed to be deciphered however I don't know how.
I found the spectrogram which outlines the words "youtube", so I suspect the final answer might have a youtube link.

the audio file name was "19559q", could that mean something?

Kindly help.[image]

https://gemoo.com/tools/upload-video/share/589650065865265152?codeId=P5GeRKpNlNGra&card=589650061683544064&origin=videolinkgenerator
This is the audio, it's in a link as I can't directly attatch it

Comment: Could you provide some more information as to what the question was? You have to decipher but what is the purpose of this? Is it part of a contest that has to do with gaming, audio forensics, security, or what?

Comment: Yes hello ZaellixA.
This is a challenge my professor provided for the class to do in our free time if we want to do it or not. 
Trying to decipher the audio however I am unsure how to do so.

Comment: Are you sure that the deciphering is not the “YouTube” part? I mean, judging from the spectrogram I don’t think this will sound like something acoustically discernible, which is what I thought when I listened to the audio too.

Comment: I am honestly not sure. He only provided us with the audio and nothing else, no instructions. The only hint was to use a spectrogram, to which i got "youtube".
i thought it had something to do with the raw code of the audio then deciphering it, but it isnt going so well.

Comment: I believe the “YouTube message” is what your professor was referring to when he was saying “decipher the hidden message”.

Comment: so do you know what to do..?

Comment: What I suggest is that you've already done what you had to do... This was the deciphering process, to find the message. Unless the "end-product" of your "search" is something that you haven't mentioned yet, I think there's nothing else to do.

Comment: youtube isnt the final answer..
i think we have to look at the raw data and decipher it to get something.. this was only the spectrogram